# onclick event handler for checkbox exhibiting inconsistent behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have isolated a hard-to-track bug in a large application to the following minimum working example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        function OnClickHandler (t) {
            t.disabled = true;
            var n = parseInt (t.getAttribute ("num"));
            document.body.appendChild (document.createTextNode (
                "num = " + t.getAttribute ("num") + ", checked = " + t.checked.toString () + " | "
            ));
            t.setAttribute ("num", n + 1);
            t.disabled = false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" num="0" onclick="OnClickHandler(this)" />
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

What I am expecting is that there will be perfect synchronisation between the value of the `num` attribute and the checked state of the check box.  But this condition does not hold, something that can be seen by clicking on the check box very rapidly.  The following is a sample output:

> Input:  two very rapid clicks, short pause, two very rapid clicks,
> short pause, single click
>
> num = 0, checked = true | num = 1, checked = true | num = 2, checked
> = false | num = 3, checked = false | num = 4, checked = true |

The intention of the logic is that the `num` attribute only change when the check state changes.  A lot of the subsequent logic of the application depends on this synchronisation.  What is the recommended way to implement this synchronization?

Comment: have you tried using onchange with the checkbox rather than onclick?

Comment: Thank you very much!  Yes, that was the correct solution, and I discovered it almost immediately after posting it.  If you post your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: lovely 15 points to me! horah! lol thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using onchange with the checkbox rather than onclick?

Comment: It says that I can accept the answer only after 10 minutes.  I'll do that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I discovered my problem almost immediately after posting the question.  My mistake is quite elementary, but I thought I would post my response anyway.

It would appear that the correct implementation should use `onchange` instead of `onclick` for the checkbox.  So, the code should look something like this:

> Test page
>       
>           function OnClickHandler (t) {
>               t.disabled = true;
>               var n = parseInt (t.getAttribute ("num"));
>               document.body.appendChild (document.createTextNode (
>                   "num = " + t.getAttribute ("num") + ", checked = " + t.checked.toString () + " | "
>               ));
>               t.setAttribute ("num", n + 1);
>               t.disabled = false;
>           }

Hope this saves some poor soul a few grey hairs.